# How do I return the local time portion of a string given a date string

Tags: react-native, datetime

I am wanting to display in a react native app a date given by the API.

The API is returning the following value:
"2022-06-20T14:00:00.000"

I need to display to the user
2:00 PM

The problem is that when I try this:

```
const dateString = "2022-06-20T14:00:00.000"
const date = new Date(dateString);
console.log(date)
```

The date has been changed to:
2022-06-20T14:00:00.000Z

Meaning it is 2pm UTC time when it should be 2pm local time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use moment library with its localized formats,
here is the documentation for more of its formats https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

```
const dateString = "2022-06-20T14:00:00.000"
console.log(moment(dateString).format('LT'))
```

Answer (score 1):

On the end of the new Date variable, if you add the .toLocaleTimeString(), it should then output as 2:00:00PM.

const date = new Date(dateString).toLocaleTimeString();